# Entity Framework Code First - redundant IDs

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

How can I get rid of a redundant ID?

I have a userprofile model - a userprofile has a list of connection models. A connection model has a userprofile (the userprofile that owns the connection) and a userprofile2 (the other userprofile that the userprofile is connected to).
In my Connections table in the db I get the following columns:

**| ID | Confirmed | ConnectionType | UserProfile_UserId | UserProfile2_UserId | UserProfile_UserId1 |**

Here UserProfile_UserId will always be the same as UserProfile_UserId1. I would really like to get rid of that extra ID-column.

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Connection> Connections { get; set; }
}

public class Connection
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Confirmed { get; set; }
    public byte ConnectionType { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile2 { get; set; }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add yourself the properties to the class like this:

```
public class Connection
{
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public bool Confirmed { get; set; }
public byte ConnectionType { get; set; }
public int UserId {get; set;}
public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
public int UserId2 {get; set;}
public virtual UserProfile UserProfile2 { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for you comment. Yes, I tried that (and many other things). Actually (ironically after just making this post) I finally found the solution. Using InverseProperty made it work:

Comment: [InverseProperty("Connections")]
        public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

Comment: You should post your answer so it will help others in the future who can have the same problem.

Comment: Will do - but I'm not allowed until after 8 hours :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using InverseProperty annotation solved the problem:
[InverseProperty("Connections")] 
public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

This is described here under InverseProperty:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/data/jj591583.aspx#Relationships